# Default column value based on the value of a identity column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to have a default value based on the value of the identity column?

i.e.

```
alter table myTable 
     add constraint df_columnX 
     default ident_current('myTable') 
     for columnX
```

Is there another way? I want the current identity for the insert statement

I want to avoid using a trigger och stored procedure

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be easier to answer if you explained why you would want to do this. The only reason I can think of would be so that you can use the identity column value but be able to overwrite it with another value in some cases but not all.

If this is your goal, having a nullable column and then 'coalesce'ing with the identity column when reading the data would do the job.

Sorry if I have misunderstood.

Comment: I'm using NHibernate to save a record in a legacy database. Inserts was previously handled by a stored procedure that updated a column to the value of the primary key. The column is "not null".

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that identity values can have default values, but you can check the following link to get the last insert identity value

[@@Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)